# Python 3: Variable becomes unresolved when redefined in scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, pycharm

I'm writing a decorator, and there is some weird behavior with variable scope on the inner functions if I try to redefine any of them anywhere.

```
def decorate_me(a_variable: bool):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            print(a_variable)
            new_variable = not a_variable
            new_variable = not new_variable
            print(new_variable)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Works as expected, no problems there. But, if a_variable is redefined at the end:

```
def decorate_me(self, a_variable: bool):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            print(a_variable)
            new_variable = not a_variable
            new_variable = not new_variable
            print(new_variable)
            
            # --- --- --- --- --- ---
            # THIS LINE RIGHT HERE
            # --- --- --- --- --- ---
            a_variable = not a_variable

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This raises an error:

```
File "...", line 41, in wrapper
    print(a_variable)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a_variable' referenced before assignment
```

How does redefining a variable cause it to be unbound on a statement several lines above the redefinition? What is the rule here and how can this be avoided?

Comment: `nonlocal` should probably fix it, but i do wonder why is this happening. I suppose, when there is no redefining of a variable, python treats it as a nonlocal variable, but when there is one, then it is treated as local. And judging by the situation, it can not track "locality" dynamically. So at interpretation stage variable is marked as local, therefore throwing errors when accessed before defining, even though there is a nonlocal value present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value), and explained [here by Eli Bendersky](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/). It's the first thing that comes up when you google 'Python UnboundLocalError'.

From Python's FAQ:

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable. Consequently when the earlier print(x) attempts to print the uninitialized local variable and an error results.

Simply, redefining the variable redefines its scope, and thus removes the variable from the outer scope.

The solution to this is to use the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords. In the example in question, `global` will not work (as `a_variable`) is not global, but `nonlocal` will work. Explicitly, it tells the inner function to use the variable in the outer scope.

Eli Bendersky's explanation goes further in depth on why this happens, and is worth reading.